# Netatalk Spotlight indexing hangs

Tags: netatalk

I have set up a Netatalk server and I'm stuck configuring the spotlight search. The server is ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've installed the tracker and the miner that are required for indexing. According to the guide [(here)](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/configuration.html#idp139639144340800) on the netatalk wiki, there is no further configuration needed. I had to fiddle around with the dbus-sessions, but the tracker works. The miner instead doesn't.

Now for some console output. The tracker itself seems to work:

```
# tracker-control 
Found 174 PIDs…
Prozesskennung 2765 für »tracker-store« gefunden
Prozesskennung 2786 für »tracker-miner-fs« gefunden

Speichern:
13 Dez 2013, 10:03:28:  ✓     Store                      - Leerlauf 

Indizierer:
13 Dez 2013, 10:03:28:    0%  Dateisystem                - Initialisierung 
13 Dez 2013, 10:03:28:  ✓     Anwendungen                - Leerlauf 
13 Dez 2013, 10:03:28:  ✗     E-Mails                    - Läuft nicht oder Plugin ist deaktiviert
```

Sorry for the german here, but it basically says, that the tracker has found the miner und the filesystem miner is initialising. Following the tracker state with option -F shows no activity, exept that my applications directory is crawled.

strace shows following:

```
# strace -p 12043
Process 12043 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>
```

Now the log from tracker-miner-fs: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mfeqep5Z)

You see, that the applications directory is crawled like it should, but after this is finished, it stops.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I forgot to

```
set spotlight = yes
```

in the afp.conf It now works like a charm.